# mysql - can I query how many connect_errors a given host gave?

Tags: mysql, high-availability, login-control

MySQL has a policy to deny a host from reconnecting once it has reached configurable failed numbher of login attempts.

This can be set using `@@global.max_connect_errors`.
See here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blocked-host.html

What I can't find and would be greatful if anybody can point me the way - is to ask the DB how many failed connection attempts has the DB experienced from a given host.

I'm working on a High-Availability setup between few nodes, and it's important for me to find this out - especially in our testing and integration environments.

Anybody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try reading from [performance_schema.host_cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/host-cache-table.html). This is a dynamic view into the internal host cache, which tracks errors per host.

As you probably know, the data tracked by the host cache is reset when you execute the statement `FLUSH HOSTS`.

You need to be using MySQL 5.6 and have the performance_schema enabled (which it should be by default).

```
mysql> select * from host_cache limit 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                                        IP: 192.168.48.95
                                      HOST: app.mcappface.example.com
                            HOST_VALIDATED: YES
                        SUM_CONNECT_ERRORS: 0
                 COUNT_HOST_BLOCKED_ERRORS: 0
           COUNT_NAMEINFO_TRANSIENT_ERRORS: 0
           COUNT_NAMEINFO_PERMANENT_ERRORS: 0
                       COUNT_FORMAT_ERRORS: 0
           COUNT_ADDRINFO_TRANSIENT_ERRORS: 0
           COUNT_ADDRINFO_PERMANENT_ERRORS: 0
                       COUNT_FCRDNS_ERRORS: 0
                     COUNT_HOST_ACL_ERRORS: 0
               COUNT_NO_AUTH_PLUGIN_ERRORS: 0
                  COUNT_AUTH_PLUGIN_ERRORS: 0
                    COUNT_HANDSHAKE_ERRORS: 0
                   COUNT_PROXY_USER_ERRORS: 0
               COUNT_PROXY_USER_ACL_ERRORS: 0
               COUNT_AUTHENTICATION_ERRORS: 0
                          COUNT_SSL_ERRORS: 0
         COUNT_MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS_ERRORS: 0
COUNT_MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR_ERRORS: 0
             COUNT_DEFAULT_DATABASE_ERRORS: 0
                 COUNT_INIT_CONNECT_ERRORS: 0
                        COUNT_LOCAL_ERRORS: 0
                      COUNT_UNKNOWN_ERRORS: 0
                                FIRST_SEEN: 2018-03-01 19:54:39
                                 LAST_SEEN: 2018-03-19 16:13:06
                          FIRST_ERROR_SEEN: NULL
                           LAST_ERROR_SEEN: NULL
```